# How to use a single grep command to search a pattern from different unix servers

Tags: unix, grep

For Example,

I have two servers namely A and B. I want to use a grep command in either A or B, which will search in both A and B servers and display the match.

Comment: See: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/161636/how-to-do-a-grep-on-remote-machine-and-print-out-the-line-which-contains-those-w

Answer (score 2):

You could use parallel ssh (pssh) for that.

See this command:

```
parallel-ssh -P -v -l root -A -H "192.168.1.1 192.168.1.2 192.168.1.3" "hostname"
```

Where `hostname` is the command to execute on each of the hosts. `-P` means print the output of the command, `-l root` means login with the user root, `-A` ask for the password and `-H` provides the list of hosts.

The output might look similar to this:

```
192.168.140.193: hostname1
192.168.140.194: hostname2
192.168.140.195: hostname3
[1] 11:18:17 [SUCCESS] 192.168.140.193
[2] 11:18:17 [SUCCESS] 192.168.140.194
[3] 11:18:17 [SUCCESS] 192.168.140.195
```

Answer (score 1):

For those without access to parallel-ssh, try this:

```
#!/bin/bash

remotehost='hostnameA'
if [ `hostname` == 'hostnameA' ]
    then
        remotehost='hostnameB'
fi
{
    grep whatever
    ssh $remotehost grep whatever
}
```

The first part figures out what host you're on and which it needs to `ssh` into.  The second part performs the command on both hosts and groups the output together.

Comment: Hi.. Thanks for the answer. But, it asks password everytime while running the script.

Comment: @Kalpana That will happen any time you open an ssh tunnel unless you set it up to use a cryptographic key http://www.linuxproblem.org/art_9.html